Get column sum/total of material-react-table row for few column like total earning from earning section and total deduction from dedcuction section
I'm preparing the employee salary table which have columns like below.
[Actual Table which is material-react-table] https://i.sstatic.net/zVbnD.png)
const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
          {
            accessorKey: 'id',
            header: 'Id',
            enableEditing: false,
            size: 80,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'firstName',
            header: 'First Name',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'lastName',
            header: 'Last Name',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'wageRate',
            header: 'Wage Rate',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'noOfDayswork',
            header: 'No Of Days Work',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'overtimeHrs',
            header: 'Overtime Hours',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'basicWage',
            header: 'Basic Wage',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'specialBasic',
            header: 'Special Basic',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'wageDA',
            header: 'DA',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'totalWage',
            header: 'Total Wage',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'paymentovertime',
            header: 'Payment Overtime',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'HRA',
            header: 'HRA',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'otherSpecialAllows',
            header: 'Other Special Allows',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'grandTotal',
            header: 'Grand Total',
            aggregationFn: 'sum',
            AggregatedCell: ({ cell }) => <div>Total Score: {cell.getValue()}</div>,
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductPf',
            header: 'PF',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductESIC',
            header: 'ESIC',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductSociety',
            header: 'Society',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductPT',
            header: 'Proffessional Tax',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductInsurance',
            header: 'Insurance',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductOthers',
            header: 'Others',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'deductRecoveries',
            header: 'Recoveries',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'totalDeduction',
            header: 'Total Deduction',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'netPayment',
            header: 'Net Payment',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
          {
            accessorKey: 'pfEmployer',
            header: 'PF by Employer',
            enableEditing: false,
          },
        ],
        [],
    );


    function useGetWages() {
      return useQuery({
       queryKey: ['wage'],
       queryFn: async () => {
        //send api request here
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); 
        return Promise.resolve(fakeData);
      },
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    });
   }

Can someone help me out with this issue? I'm unable to prepare table to Totals, NetSalary, Total etc. All formula added in the image table.
Thanks in advance.
I tried in my react component with the material-react-table.

I have tried with all the possibilities; can someone help me out with this issue solution.

{
id: 3,
firstName: 'Molly',
wageRate: 650,
noOfDayswork: 27,
basicWage:419,
wageDA:0,
totalWage:11313,
paymentovertime:0,
HRA:21,
otherSpecialAllows:260,
grandTotal:17549,
deductPf:1358,
deductESIC:132,
deductSociety:0,
deductPT:200,
totalDeduction:1690,
netPayment:15859,
pfEmployer:1488,
dateOfPayment:0,
remarkOfPayment:"remark ok"
},

I have used the custom calculations in the material-react-table. Below is the solution, which worked for me:
accessorFn: (row) => row.noOfDayswork * (row.basicWage + row.wageDA),
Cell: ({ renderedCellValue, row }) => {           
    return (<span>
                {renderedCellValue}
            </span>)
}


while using the accessorKey in MRT, you should either use id with accessorFn or accessorKey
